# How to use one controller for multiple inputs with the same logic?

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-model

I have the following scenario, one form with multiple inputs and i need to calculate every input the same way but return the values to different fields

```
<div class="row">
        <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="InputValorFOR" placeholder="" ng-change="findModifier()" ng-model="atrb.for">
        <p>{{mod.for}}</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="InputValorDES" placeholder="" ng-change="findModifier()" ng-model="atrb.des">
        <p>{{mod.des}}</p>
</div>
```

the controller:

```
app.controller('atributosCtrl', function($scope){

findModifier = function() {        
    if ($scope.atrb > 1 && $scope.atrb <10)
    {
        if ($scope.atrb % 2 == 0)
        {
            $scope.mod = (($scope.atrb / 2) - 5);
        }        
    }
};    
$scope.$watch('atrb', findModifier); });
```

I want to change the value of mod.for or mod.des without having to write a controller for each input. but i don't how to pass the name of the model from the input that i'm modifying

Comment: why not use `ng-change="findModifier(<string>)"`

Comment: didn't know that i could do that, tks! Waldir's answer with the plnkr helped me to understand how to get there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want, but I made some changes on your code to make it working. Please tell me what you want in comments here and I'll can help you.

Your HTML modified:

```
  <body ng-controller="atributosCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="InputValorFOR" placeholder="" ng-change="findModifier('for')" ng-model="atrb.for">
        <p>{{mod.for}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="InputValorDES" placeholder="" ng-change="findModifier('des')" ng-model="atrb.des">
        <p>{{mod.des}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Your JS modified:

```
app.controller('atributosCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.atrb = {
    for: null,
    des: null
  };
  $scope.mod = {
    for: null,
    des: null
  };

  $scope.findModifier = function(type) {
    $scope.mod[type] = null;
    if ($scope.atrb[type] > 1 && $scope.atrb[type] <10)
    {
        if ($scope.atrb[type] % 2 === 0)
        {
            $scope.mod[type] = (($scope.atrb[type] / 2) - 5);
        }        
    }
  }
});
```

Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/aCNJQyfYXZ5vU1rc381S

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting somethin like this. You can write a custom directive with a link function like below

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app").directive("notifypropertychanged", notifypropertychanged);
    function notifypropertychanged() {
        var directive = {
            require: "ngModel",
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                $scope.$watch(attrs["notifypropertychanged"], function (newVal, oldVal) {

                    var initialValue = attrs["oldvalue"];

                });
            }
        };
        return directive;
    }
})();
```

Apply this directive on your input

```
 <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" notifypropertychanged="atrb.des"  oldvalue=" {{::atrb.des}} " id="InputValorDES" placeholder="" ng-model="atrb.des">
```

whenever the value change it will hit on custom **watch**

I hope this helps

Comment: this is correct and a good answer to use the directive and the watch, but i choose Waldir's answer because was simpler and direct to solve the problem, tks